# VBA excel Passing back parameter

Tags: vba, excel

Okay I want to add something to this macro

```
Sub Search()
  Inputbox myInput                      
  found = false
  loop
     Call getInput (myInput)            '~> check multiple files
  end loop
  If found = false
    'DO something   
  End if
End sub

Sub getInput(ByVal inputVar As String, ByVal Input as Boolean)
  If a = inputVar Then                  
      found = true                      '~> I want to pass this parameter back to search
  End If
End sub
```

---

> The case is like, I want my sub to pass the **found** parameter from
>   Search() to getInput() and then getInput() return the **found** parameter to
>   Search()

Should I add something like search(ByVal found as boolean) ?

Comment: what is `a` in your `getInput` Sub? and your loop syntax is invalid..

Comment: Function can return values.  Have you tried them out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to return a value, then you should change the getInput Sub to a function as they can return values.

```
Sub Search()
  Dim found As Boolean

  InputBox myInput

  found = checkInput(myInput)

  If found = False Then
    'DO something
  End If
End Sub

Function checkInput(inputVar As String) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean

    'do your checking here and set result

    'return the result
    checkInput = result

End Function
```